# Count Git commits per period

Tags: git, github

is there a way to count the number of commits in certain period (e.g. the last year from 2015-03-01 to 2016-03-01) for git (GitHub) repositories?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

To count the commits in a date range in your current branch do this:

```
 git rev-list --count HEAD --since="Dec 3 2015"  --before="Jan 3 2016"
```

If you want the count for all branches in one go use --all additionally

```
git rev-list --count --since="Dec 3 2015"  --before="Jan 3 2016" --all
```

if you want to exclude merge-commits, use option --no-merges

```
git rev-list --count --since="Dec 3 2015"  --before="Jan 3 2016" --all --no-merges
```

Comment: per branch, please? PS. Got it: --branches[=<pattern>]

Answer (score 6):

You can get total number of commits through a time period with two different ways:

### First way

Get the total commit by using [second - minute - hour - day - week - month - year]

> Get the total commits by second

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=600.second
```

> Get the total commits by minute

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=30.minute
```

> Get the total commits by hour

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=3.hour
```

> Get the total commits by day

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=28.day
```

> Get the total commits by week

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=4.week
```

> Get the total commits by month

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=1.month
```

> Get the total commits by year

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=1.year
```

### Second way

Using since and before - since take the start date and before take the end date that you want to get commit from it.

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD --since="Dec 1 2021"  --before="Jan 3 2022"
```

You can get all commits by selecting the branch name:

```bash
git rev-list --count master --since="Dec 1 2021"  --before="Jan 3 2022"
```

Comment: How could I filter the commit messages? eg. I want the metrics for commits with a message that contains a common string

Comment: You will use grep  with log ```git log --oneline |grep -i "put_string_here"``` ,  you will put pattern between double quotation, `-i`  for ignore case sensitive.